# reading from file to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am having some issues when trying to get hold of the data in a text file in the next form:

```
12
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
3.4
4.0
2.5
3.4
1000
1500
1000
```

As you can see, the first figure in the first line is always the amount of elements in the second line.
My hideous code is like this so far:

```
parametros=fopen("lyapunov.params", "r");
    if(parametros == NULL){
        printf("\nSe toman valores por defecto.\n");
    }else{  //Se asume que el fichero tiene las lineas correctas.
        for(line=0; line<9; line++){
            if(line == 0){
                fscanf(parametros, "%d", seq_length);
            }
            if(line == 1){
                fscanf(parametros, "%d", &seq[i++]);
            }
            if(line == 2){
                fscanf(parametros, "%f", amin);
            }
            if(line == 3){
                fscanf(parametros, "%f", amax);
            }
            if(line == 4){
                fscanf(parametros, "%f", bmin);
            }
            if(line == 5){
                fscanf(parametros, "%f", bmax);
            }
            if(line == 6){
                fscanf(parametros, "%d", asize);
            }
            if(line == 7){
                fscanf(parametros, "%d", bsize);
            }
            if(line == 8){
                fscanf(parametros, "%d", nmax);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(parametros);
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You forgot the loop for read the values of the second line.

Comment: You need to read each line into a buffer, such as `fgets()`, then parse the line according to its content into the target array.

Comment: You could have omitted the loop and every `if(line == X)` and just used the 9 lines which do `fscanf()`. But use a loop within that to read the second line values, as @NetVipeC comment.

Comment: Every `scanf()` line that does not have the ampersand `&` "address of" in front of the last argument - should have. For example `if(line == 8) {fscanf(parametros, "%d", &nmax);}`

Answer (score 1):

Working complete example:

The principal change are in:

- Loop in line two to read all the values, as I suggest in the comments.
- Change the variables to values and use `&variable` in `fscanf`
- Eliminate the unnecessary if (with variable line)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENT 100
int main(void) {
    FILE* parametros;
    int reading_error = 0;
    int i;
    int seq_length = 0, asize = 0, bsize = 0, nmax = 0;
    float amin = 0, amax = 0, bmin = 0, bmax = 0;
    int seq[MAX_ELEMENT];
    parametros = fopen("E:\\test.txt", "r");
    if (parametros == NULL) {
        printf("\nSe toman valores por defecto.\n");
    } else { // Se asume que el fichero tiene las lineas correctas.
        reading_error += 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%d", &seq_length);
        if (seq_length > MAX_ELEMENT) {
            // handle error
        }
        for (i = 0; i < seq_length;) {
            reading_error = 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%d", &seq[i++]);
        }
        reading_error += 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%f", &amin);
        reading_error += 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%f", &amax);
        reading_error += 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%f", &bmin);
        reading_error += 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%f", &bmax);
        reading_error += 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%d", &asize);
        reading_error += 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%d", &bsize);
        reading_error += 1 != fscanf(parametros, "%d", &nmax);
        fclose(parametros);
    }

    if (!reading_error) {
        printf("%d\n", seq_length);
        for (i = 0; i < seq_length;) {
            printf("%d ", seq[i++]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("%f\n", amin);
        printf("%f\n", amax);
        printf("%f\n", bmin);
        printf("%f\n", bmax);
        printf("%d\n", asize);
        printf("%d\n", bsize);
        printf("%d\n", nmax);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming file is in correct format: not checking the return value of `fscanf()`, not checking if `seq[100]` is big enough.

Comment: I really like this solution except that I would have used a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant "As you can see, the first figure in the first line is always the amount of elements in NEXT  line.", then your data does not reflect that.

Write a function that reads a single set of data by first reading n then looping to read n elements.

Call this function repeatedly until EOF is encountered.